# is it possible to integrate a html5/js game as a facebook app?

Tags: javascript, facebook, html

I want to know if it is possible to integrate a html5/js game as a facebook application (create a facebookb application using html5/js)
how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. In fact that is what a Facebook app is. An embedded HTML5/JS doc.

All you gotta do is upload your working HTML on a server and give it's link as canvas url in a new app on [developers.facebook.com](http://developers.facebook.com) and voila! Your game is up and running as an app!

[Here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OFdansAKreY)'s a youtube video explaining step by step the process of making an app. Check out the related links for more tutorials.

Also read about canvas [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/canvas/).

Comment: I didn't look up the video, but writing from experience here. It is necessary to have a ssl certificate(https) in order to properly publish a facebook game.